# How to pass function return to modal in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I only have one week experience with swift/programming so bear with me. I stripped down the app I am working on to simplify my problem. I am trying to pass the return values from my function grandCalc to my modal so that I can show the total and tip value on both my main view and my modal. I'm on Xcode 11.5, SwiftUI.

Here is the modal where I would like to show the tip value

```
struct ModalView: View {
    var body: some View {

        // Want to show tip value here
        // Error: use of unresolved identifier grandCalc
        Text("\(grandCalc().theTipValue)")
    }
}
```

Here is all of the code. I could use a push in the right direction, thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var checkAmount = "10.00"
@State var tipValue = 15.0
@State var modalDisplayed = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("\(grandCalc().theGrandTotal)")
            Text("\(grandCalc().theTipValue)")
            Button(action: {
                self.modalDisplayed.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Details")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $modalDisplayed) {
                ModalView()
            }
        }
    }
}

func grandCalc() -> (theTipValue: Double, theGrandTotal: Double) {
    let tipSelection = Double(tipValue)
    let orderAmount = Double(checkAmount) ?? 0

    let tipValue = orderAmount / 100 * tipSelection
    let grandTotal = orderAmount + tipValue
    return (tipValue, grandTotal)
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Want to show tip value here
        Text("\(grandCalc().theTipValue)")
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Define these 2 properties in `ModalView`, initialize the object by passing these values in: `ModalView(total: grandCalc().theGrandTotal, tip: grandCalc().theTipValue)`

Comment: Great! This answered my question, thank you